# fast execution analitycs database with thousand rows to displaying in php

Tags: mysql, database-design, php

i've table with a thousand rows and i want to creating analitycs with chart display my front end php

my table structure is

[image: Database Structure]

and how i display this data : 
[image: Display in my dashboard]

by `user_agent` column i display operating system, browsers, and devices.

for now i still using the old algorithm with looping using `for ()` method and parsing each rows. And it takes a long time respond and displaying the data.

anyone knows how i can display this data without take long respond in my website? any idea? with the database structure or my php script?

Thankyou before.

Comment: Are you talking about a PHP `for` loop that you are using to collect data for presentation or are you talking about a MySQL `for` loop that you are using to prepare the data for returning to your front end (PHP)? If it's the former, yours is not a database problem then, but rather a presentation problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with database administration.

Comment: im talking about php loop. its take so long execution time to parsing and displaying data for the presentation. how to move it into mysql looping? or any idea how to make it more faster?

Comment: What is your query? What about `GROUP BY` maybe? Though if you have a lot of data, you might want to rethink your schema or use cache.

Comment: schema or using chache ok. thx for your information. really helpful

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're loading all your data in a PHP script and postprocessing it in a for-loop in PHP, you should alter your database query. A `GROUP BY` statement might help. Of course, you need to alter your script to work with the new data. Revisiting your database structure is a good idea, too. A better approach might be not to save the whole user-agent string in one column but to use several columns.

Example before:

```
$data = $db->query('SELECT * FROM table');
for ($i = 0; $i <= $data->max(); i++) {
  $row = $data->getRow($i);
  postprocessRow($row); /* $sum += 1; */
}
```

Example after:

```
$data = $db->query('SELECT count(*) as weight, * FROM table GROUP BY user_agent');
for ($i = 0; $i <= $data->max(); i++) {
  $row = $data->getRow($i);
  postprocessRowWeighted($row); /* $sum += $row['weight']; */
}
```